Validate CRUD permission before SOQL/DML operation
I have a existing class with 2000 lines of code.
I got a requirement to "Validate CRUD permission before SOQL/DML operation".
Also, I have been given a list of Profiles and Permission sets that should have access to.
I believe the solution is:
Post Spring 20 release, all we have to do is add all the SOQL queries in the class "WITH SECURITY_ENFORCED" clause?
Do we need to handle the insufficient permissions exception?
Please correct me, if I am wrong.
Thanks in advance.

Check this: https://www.sfdcstop.com/2020/03/validate-crud-permission-before-soqldml.html

https://www.janbasktraining.com/community/salesforce/how-can-i-validate-crud-permission-before-execution-of-the-soql-queries-or-dml-operation


Welcome to SFSE.  Please take a moment to read [ask] and take the [tour]. Please [edit] your post to explain further what kind of validation you want to do.

You need to specify a bit more what constitutes "validate" in your situation. It seems like you are asking about a business requirement, and that the person who wrote it didn't provide enough details on what or why to do that.
One can query only accessible fields with the WITH SECURITY_ENFORCED clause in queries, for sure. But you can also leverage the Security class for this task, so your code can query all fields and then you can strip the records away from the fields that the current user does not have access to. And you can get the indexes that were modified in the list, get the records without the inaccessible fields and get the removed fields from the records on that list.
